# Normal scrollbars in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

I have problems working with the new small (HTML scripted) scrollbars in Google Docs.

Is there some way to get normal (operating system provided) scrollbars back?
Maybe some jQuery in a Chrome extension, or some CSS trickery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this Extension, which works in Google Sheets:
Rescroller
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rescroller/ddehdnnhjimbggeeenghijehnpakijod/related?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution (as much as I love Chrome) would be to use another browser.

For example, Firefox

[image: Firefox does not have small scrollbar]

Comment: I like the idea. :)